# Trade reputation for a decrease in account suspension time

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, account-suspension

What do you think about being able to trade reputation for a decrease in account suspension time? It would still be a punishment, and the amount of reputation lost should be calculated according to the severity of the suspension's reason, and the amount of suspension time decrease a user would like to 'buy'. It would be like paying bail, probably available only in certain moderator-selected cases.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this is a very bad idea. Reputation represents your participation in the site. A suspension indicates something you've done is "bad" and outside the normal functioning of the site (where downvotes etc would be the punishment). You shouldn't be able to buy your way out of being a jerk.

Answer (score 21):

I've got a better idea - don't get your account suspended in the first place.

Comment: That's not exactly helpful as long as my question targeted the cases that do actually involve account suspension... it's like suggesting that a good advice regarding the rights of people that get arrested is not to get arrested in the first place :)

Comment: Actually, I think that's pretty good advice, too, especially since in this case you get warned before you get suspended thus getting a chance to both avoid the suspension and any loss to your real reputation.

Comment: Not in my case, I did not receive any warning whatsoever. I do admit it might have been a justified decision, but it stands as a particular case where your warning argument doesn't hold. I presume there might be other cases as well, where people got their accounts suspended without any warning, thus making it quite valid to be allowed at least a reputation trade-in.